# Issue when trying to run passenger on Apache

Tags: apache, passenger

I am getting this issue when running

`httpd -t`

`httpd: Syntax error on line 545 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /private/etc/apache2/other/passenger.conf: Cannot load /Users/sbaidon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.5/b
uildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: dlopen(/Users/sbaidon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.5/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Users/sbaidon/.rv
m/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.5/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so: code signature in (/Users/sbaidon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.5/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so) not valid for use in p
rocess using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.\n\t/Users/sbaidon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/passenger-5.3.5/buildout/apache2/mod_passen
ger.so: stat() failed with errno=22`

Passenger installation is just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this too: the issue is that the built-in httpd that comes with macOS Mojave has Library Validation turned on, which means any modules it loads must be properly signed.  Unfortunately, mod_passenger.so is not signed, so loading fails.  Actually, a lot of people are having this problem with loading Apache modules on macOS Mojave (especially during the beta), some example references:

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/357
https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1406

I believe it's possible to set up a plist somewhere to give an entitlement to httpd to disable library validation (com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation) as described at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/com_apple_security_cs_disable-library-validation.  For instance, here's a recent WebKit patch where they add it to allow plugin loading: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183252.  Similarly, here's the Mozilla people talking about how they need to enable this (and other) properties: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?format=default&id=1470597.

Unfortunately, I don't do macOS development (I just do development *on* macOS) and I have absolutely no idea how to apply it to the built-in Apache, I'm sorry.

At this point I'm kind of sick of every major macOS update nerfing all my httpd settings and generally being a pain (it's infrequent but it's still annoying), so I'm doing what I should have done years ago: stop using the built-in httpd that comes with OS/X and just use Homebrew httpd.

Here's some instructions I found regarding setting up Homebrew httpd (and disabling the built-in macOS httpd), it's pretty straightforward and you don't have to follow *all* of the directions about multiple PHP versions etc: https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-mojave-apache-multiple-php-versions

If someone can figure out how to disable Library Validation in the built-in httpd, or if there is some way to provide signing on mod_passenger.so (seems unlikely since both the Homebrew and gem passenger need to be buildable from source), you don't need to junk the built-in httpd.  But I personally think the best solution is to move away from it entirely and use the Homebrew version instead.

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I ended up doing just using a custom apache install

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue or any issue with library validation in macOS Mojave, I found an incredibly easy fix to disable it. https://github.com/mologie/macos-disable-library-validation

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in macOS 10.14.4