# Mac Mojave - can't execute php files with Apache2 web server

Tags: php, macos, apache2, macos-mojave

Mac OS 10.14 - Mojave:

> can't run php  web pages on Apache2 server:

Apache Logger file shows PHP module load:

> [Sun Nov 04 01:15:44.594704 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31049] AH00163: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Sun Nov 04 01:15:44.594789 2018] [core:notice] [pid 31049] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS -D FOREGROUND'

`$> php -v`     on command line shows version 7.1.19:

> PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 18:03:17) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Ideas?

Comment: hmmm, setting httpd.conf port to 8080 lets     localhost:8080/info.php   execute properly.... looking at adjusting port to be the default....

Comment: please clarify where and when you get the *can't run php web pages on Apache2 server* message

Comment: YakovL - Mac Mojave 10.14 web pages that I used to run on laptop's Server/Apache2, but with update to Mojave I activated Apache2  separately from Server app. So...php used to run in low port address stopped working. All I see is php page source, on the lower port. On port 8080 it works fine. That's enough, but I'd like to understand why I can't use lower port.Start Apache2 httpd with 'root' permission. 
root# php --version
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Nick

Answer (score 6):

I had to add this to private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf (or if you prefer into a .htaccess file, for an example ~/Sites/.htaccess).

```
# PHP 7 specific configuration
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No. didn't work. Already have something similar in place, although I tried this too. Still only works on the high (8080) port, not the low (80) port.

Comment: This worked for me. Upgraded from macos sierra to mojave. Surprise surprise Apache and PHP now borked. Copied httpd.conf~previous to httpd.conf and apache now works but PHP not executing just outputting source. Edited httpd.conf to load php 7 module rather 5.6, PHP still not executing. Added the ifmodule block from this answer into httpd.conf, write out, restart apache, PHP now executes. Removed everything apart from the AddType application/x-httpd-php .php line from inside of the block and it still works ok. Already had the IfModule dir_module elsewhere.

Comment: It worked. For me, my config file was at 

/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

I added this line under 

LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

Which i got when i installed PHP

Comment: It works too... therfore it's annoying to have  /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf this conf instead of existing previous /etc/apache2/ ?..

Answer (score 0):

Uncommenting the line:

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

at file */etc/apache2/httpd.conf*, and restarting apache

```
apachectl restart
```

worked for me.

Comment: Alas no:
root# grep -C1 php httpd.conf
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
#LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so
--
--
#
<IfModule php7_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
    <IfModule dir_module>
--
--
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>

Comment: This is a permissions issue with the bundled Apache in macOS Mojave. The PHP module is an unsigned module and thus isn't allowed to load.  The same this is happening with other modules from other sources.  So far the only recommended work around is to disable the built in Apache and install Apache Homebrew. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505052/issue-when-trying-to-run-passenger-on-apache